# Requests to nodejs server deployed on Azure App Service timing out when trying to access Azure Postgres flexible database

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a node.js express server deployed on Azure App Services, which connects to an Azure flexible postgresql database to serve requests. When running the server locally the postgres database can access the database fine, but when the server is deployed to an azure app service, all requests time out:
[image: Server logs of the request timing out]

The server uses a pool to make requests, this is what my server config file looks like:

```
const {Pool} = require('pg');
require('dotenv').config();

const config = {
    host: process.env.HOST,
    user: process.env.USER,
    password: process.env.PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    port: process.env.PORT,
    ssl: true,
    max: 50,
    idleTimeoutMillis: 10000,
    allowExitOnIdle: true,
}

module.exports = new Pool(config);
```

So far I've tried:

- Allowing all IP addresses to access the database
- Allowing all services within Azure to access the database
- Giving the server's App service contributor permissions to the database.

But none of these solutions have prevented requests from timing out, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have thankfully found the solution to this problem!

I suspect that the Azure App Service overrides the PORT env variable to 8080, and so the port variable used to connect to the database ends up being wrong when a connection is attempted.

I've renamed the .env variable to something else and it is now working correctly.